# Как обновить файлы на OS Store 1.5.5

Tags: php, mysql

[image: Эти ошибки возникают, когда я запускаю сайт. Не знаю как их решить]

Может обновить их через адимн панель (Shift + ПКМ) в папке, но я не знаю какие команды нужны. Запускал я интернет-магазин через OpenServer.

Строки с ошибками[![Строка 6[![][2]][2]][2]][3]

[image: Ошибки]

Ошибки:

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in W:\domains\osstorenew.loc\system\database\mysql.php on line 6

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\domains\osstorenew.loc\system\database\mysql.php:6) in W:\domains\osstorenew.loc\system\engine\controller.php on line 28

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at W:\domains\osstorenew.loc\system\database\mysql.php:6) in W:\domains\osstorenew.loc\system\engine\controller.php on line 29

Comment: Замените картинки в вопросе кодом как текст.